# Wikidata mwapi Search multiple terms at the same time

Tags: sparql, wikidata

is it possible to search multiple term at the same time ? Using the OR operator, such as if I want to search Chicago OR New York City, in media wiki api at https://query.wikidata.org/

Below is example of search just Chicago, also how to search exact term ? I don't want "123 Chicago" to be returned, I just want "Chicago"

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
 SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
   bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org";
   wikibase:api "EntitySearch";
   mwapi:search "Chicago"; 
   mwapi:language "en".
   ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
 }
  
 SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".}
}
```

Comment: multiple terms: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  VALUES ?term {"Chicago" "Boston"}
 SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
   bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org";
   wikibase:api "EntitySearch";
   mwapi:search ?term; 
   mwapi:language "en".
   ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
 }
  
 SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".}
}`

Comment: for exact match, isn't it better to just use standard SPARQL? `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  VALUES ?term {"Chicago"@en "Boston"@en}
 ?item rdfs:label|skos:altLabel ?term
  
 SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".}
}`

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks a lot, that multiple terms works well. For the exact match, searching the label directly is very slow in wikidata, according to their sparql optimization tips, they recommend using mwapi to be faster https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/query_optimization#Searching_labels

Comment: @UninformedUser 
I am trying to improve this this type of query that takes about 20 seconds 

`SELECT DISTINCT ?ent ?wdtProperty ?val ?valLabel WHERE { 
  
  ?val wdt:P31|wdt:P106 [ rdfs:label|skos:altLabel 'journalist'@en ]. 
  ?ent rdfs:label|skos:altLabel "Chicago"@en. 
  ?wdProperty2 rdfs:label|skos:altLabel "place of birth"@en; 
  wikibase:directClaim ?wdtProperty2. 
  
  ?val ?wdtProperty2 ?ent . 
  OPTIONAL { ?val rdfs:label ?valLabel FILTER(lang(?valLabel) = "en") } } LIMIT 10`

Comment: Why are you adding four levels of indirection? It's no wonder it won't work. There are hundreds of examples integrated into the query interface, so I really don't understand where you picked up that convolution scheme of yours.

Comment: @MatthiasWinkelmann hi, did you mean it should have been done like this ? `SELECT DISTINCT  ?val ?valLabel WHERE {       
  ?val wdt:P106 wd:Q1930187.    
  ?val wdt:P19 wd:Q1297 .    
  OPTIONAL { ?val rdfs:label ?valLabel FILTER(lang(?valLabel) = "en") } } LIMIT 10` If so, this is not what I am trying to do, in my application, the Q ID or Property ID is unknown before hand. I need to lookup the ID by label. I know many examples in the interface but most of them are using direct Q ID, not searching by label.

Comment: The number of properties is quite limited. So those, at least, should be retrieved once and substituted locally. Items should be cached. You are using labels as identifiers, and that's just not what they are meant to be.

Comment: @MatthiasWinkelmann for the properties, it can be replaced before running the sparql. But for the entity there are so many and many synonyms, how this can be better achieved then when the goal is to try convert natural language to sparql ?